# Synthesist Summoner, what size are you when you fuse if the Eidolon is medium and the summoner is small?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

When a small summoner summons a medium Eidolon and [fuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist) with it, what size is the resulting combination?

> The eidolon must be at least the same size as the synthesist.

Answer (score 1):

### Your size increases to match your Eidolon's

While there is no rule specifically mentioning a size increase on neither the [Synthesist's Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist/) ability, nor the [Summoner's Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Eidolon) base ability, when discussing the several [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9obd) requests about the synthesists, [Seak K Reynolds](http://paizo.com/people/SeanKReynolds) (back then, a Paizo's Developer) did give us [an example of what happens when a medium-sized summoner merges with a large-sized eidolon](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mi13&page=7?One-Synthesist-Summoner-Thread-to-rule-them-all#332):

> I've talked to Jason and updated the FAQ about share spells. To sum up: yes, a regular summoner is able to cast humanoid-only spells on his eidolon (duh); yes, a synthesist can too because it doesn't alter share spells.
>
> There is a bit of weirdness about the synthesist and enlarge person that Jason wants to think about for a bit because of the "eidolon must be at least the same size as the synthesist" rule. Basically, if you're Medium and the eidolon is Medium, should it be assumed that the spell affects you "both," or is it a weird case where the summoner "outgrows" the Medium eidolon. Likewise, **if you're Medium and the eidolon is Large, you already have the Large benefits, so turning into a Large summoner inside a Large eidolon-shell shouldn't have any effect.**
>
> Anyway, he's going to let that "roll around in the old rock tumbler," as he puts it.

Comment: If I used Evolution surge greater to gain the large evolution after fusing, would that change my size? Im asking because you get to benefit from the evolutions and size is an evolution.

Comment: All I see is that enlarge person will work on the Eidolon while fused. In this case since you are one and the same both of you should become larger. I see nothing in the FAQ about the size evolutions.

Comment: @Fering the FAQ i linked had a note at the end about size: *"FAQ pending about size-changing magic and a synthesist (because of the limitation of "the eidolon must be at least the same size as the synthesist" rule)."*

Comment: Because that question was literally skipped over during that series of FAQs, the author of that thread did ask what happens when a medium summoner merged with a large-sized eidolon, but wasn't officially answered.